# how do i write a function to generalize multiple lmer models with different response variables?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, lme4

I am trying to generalize a function that will run all these different model combinations but on different response variables.

```
`
model_suite <- function(response, df){
mod1.2 <- lmer(log(response) ~ traffic + (1 | site), data = df, na.action = na.exclude, REML = FALSE)}
#all eelgrass dry weight by site type with site as a random effect #
mod2.2 <- lmer(log(response) ~ type + (1 | site), data = df, na.action = na.exclude, REML = FALSE)
#all data by season with site as a random effect
mod3.2 <- lmer(log(response) ~ season + (1 | site), data = df, na.action = na.exclude, REML = FALSE)
#all data by traffic class and season with site as a random effect
mod4.2 <- lmer(log(response) ~ traffic * season + (1 | site), data = df, na.action = na.exclude, REML = FALSE)
mod5.2<- lmer(log(response) ~ traffic + season + (1 | site), data = df, na.action = na.exclude, REML = FALSE)
#all data by site type and season with site as a random effect
mod6.2 <- lmer(log(response) ~ type * season + (1 | site), data = df, na.action = na.exclude, REML = FALSE)
mod7.2 <- lmer(log(response) ~ type + season + (1 | site), data = df, na.action = na.exclude, REML = FALSE)
mod.sel <- model.sel(mod1.2, mod2.2, mod3.2, mod4.2, mod5.2, mod6.2, mod7.2)
print(mod.sel)
}`
```

Such that when I run this function with:

```
`model_suite(eelgrass_length, all_eelgrass) `
```

it returns this error:
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'eelgrass_length' not found

How can I generalize this to loop through these?

Comment: why not use `MuMIn::dredge()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful when using formulas in R. Names within formulas are not subtituted the way that you might expect. For example, if we do:

```r
my_formula <- function(variable) {
  formula(variable ~ other_variable)
}
```

And then run:

```r
my_formula(banana)
#> variable ~ other_variable
#> <environment: 0x000001de2e0d8900>
```

We can see that the left hand side of the formula is still `variable` - it has not been subsituted for `banana` as you might expect.

There are various ways round this. One is to create a character string from the input name using `deparse(substitute(...))` then convert it to a formula using `as.formula`.

So we can change the above function as follows:

```r
my_formula <- function(variable) {
  
  as.formula(paste(deparse(substitute(variable)), '~ other_variable'))
}
```

And now the input to the function will be substituted into the formula

```r
my_formula(banana)
#> banana ~ other_variable
#> <environment: 0x000001de2e379048>
```

This is exactly the issue with your function. `response` is not being substituted in your formulas, so your function is literally looking for a column called `response`, which doesn't exist.

The mechanism of creating formulas using `as.formula` also gives us the opportunity to remove some of the repetition in your function. We can create a `list` of formulas and loop the `lmer` calls inside `lapply`. We can then call `model.sel` directly on this list.

```r
library(lme4)
library(MuMIn)

model_suite <- function(response, df){
  lhs <- paste0('log(', deparse(substitute(response)), ') ~')
  rhs <- paste(c('traffic', 'type', 'season', 'traffic * season', 
                 'traffic + season', 'type * season', 'type + season'),
               '+ (1 | site)')
  formulas <- lapply(paste(lhs, rhs), as.formula)
  models <- lapply(formulas, function(x) {
    lmer(x, data = df, na.action = na.exclude, REML = FALSE)
  })
  do.call('model.sel', models)
}
```

This allows:

```r
model_suite(eelgrass_length, all_eelgrass)
#> Model selection table 
#>     (Int) trf typ ssn ssn:trf ssn:typ df   logLik  AICc delta weight
#> 3 -0.7877           +                  4 -138.417 285.3  0.00  0.427
#> 6 -0.3129       +   +               +  8 -134.480 286.7  1.43  0.209
#> 2 -0.8611       +                      5 -138.462 287.6  2.33  0.133
#> 7 -0.7211       +   +                  6 -137.754 288.5  3.22  0.086
#> 1 -0.8698   +                          5 -138.923 288.6  3.25  0.084
#> 5 -0.7298   +       +                  6 -138.223 289.5  4.15  0.054
#> 4 -0.7336   +       +       +          8 -137.701 293.2  7.87  0.008
#> Models ranked by AICc(x) 
#> Random terms (all models): 
#>   1 | site
```

---

**Data used**

We don't have the data you are using to run this function, and it seems that the function is dependent on having specific columns in the passed data frame. I have created a little data frame with the same names as your data so that the above code should work for your real data too:

```r
set.seed(123)
all_eelgrass <- expand.grid(traffic = c('light', 'medium', 'heavy'),
                            type = c('type1', 'type2', 'type3'),
                            season = c('dry', 'rainy'),
                            site = c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'))

all_eelgrass$eelgrass_length <- rexp(90, c(0.8, 1, 1.2, 1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.2, 1.4,
    1.6, 1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.2,  1.4, 1.6, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.2, 1.4, 
    1.6, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 1.6, 1.8, 2, 1.2, 1.4, 
    1.6, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 1.6, 1.8, 2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 1.6, 1.8, 2, 1.8, 
    2, 2.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 1.6, 1.8, 2, 1.8, 2, 2.2, 1.6, 1.8, 2, 1.8, 2, 2.2, 
    2, 2.2, 2.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2, 1.8, 2, 2.2, 2, 2.2, 2.4, 1.8, 2, 2.2, 2, 2.2, 
    2.4, 2.2, 2.4, 2.6))
```

Comment: this was so helpful, thank you so much allan!!